# Generalizing the Chi distribution to distinct variances?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

LEt $x$ be a multivariate normal random variable $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma)$, where $\Sigma\in\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a *diagonal* covariance matrix with entries $[\sigma_1^2,\dots,\sigma_n^2]$ where, in general, $\sigma_1^2\neq\dots\neq\sigma_n^2$.

In the special case of $\sigma_1^2=\dots=\sigma_n^2=1$, the norm of this random variable would be distributed according to a [Chi distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution). It is also possible to consider the case $\sigma_1^2=\dots=\sigma_n^2=c$ for some $c > 0$ with appropriate scaling. I was wondering: is it possible to derive a similar distribution for the case in which the diagonal variances are $\sigma_1^2\neq\dots\neq\sigma_n^2$? Can you recommend any resources that might discuss this topic?

(I am aware of [this similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/385538/generalized-chi-distribution), but the links provided don't seem useful.)

Comment: One source to look at is Wikipedia's page on the [generalized chi distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_chi-squared_distribution). But it's not entirely obvious to me if that maps onto what you're asking.

Comment: I answered a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3537633/89603) a while ago.  In this case, there is no closed form and you would need to approximate by truncating an infinite series. There is a relevant reference in the answer.